# rake Virtual timer expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using os x 10.6 
1.8.6 via rvm
rails 2.3.6

I can run rake or script/server  I get an error Virtual timer expired

I have seen someone else had this issue and seems, the mysql gem needs to be downgraded to 2.7

i have tried to install mysql -v=2.7

i get a different error
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

can anyone explain the proper way to get this done

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in older versions of ruby and the mysql gem that interact to cause this problem. It has been fixed in 1.8.7, but the fix was not backported to 1.8.6 because it is no longer supported.  The following patch can be applied while installing using rvm (see: http://rvm.io/rubies/patching).

https://gist.github.com/mdotterer/8807766